# Using Python to split a Unicode file object into dictionary Keys and values

Tags: python, dictionary, unicode, split

Hi and thanks for reading.  I’ll admit that this is a progression on from a previous question I asked earlier, after I partially solved the issue.  I am trying to process a block of text (file_object) in an earlier working function.  The text or file_object happens to be in Unicode, but I have managed to convert to ascii text and split on a line by line basis.  I am hoping to then further split the text on the ‘=’ symbol so that I can drop the text into a dictionary.  For example Key: Value as ‘GPS Time’:’ 14:18:43’ so removing the trailing '.000' from the time (though this is a second issue).

Here’s the file_object format…

```
2015 Jan 01  20:07:16.047 GPS Info  #Log packet ID

GPS Time = 14:18:43.000 

Longitude = 000.65341

Latitude = +41.25385

Altitude = +111.400
```

This is my partially working function…

```
def process_data(file_object):
    file_object = file_object.encode('ascii','ignore')
    split = file_object.split('\n')

    for i in range(len(split)):  
        while '=' in split[i]:
            processed_data = (split[i].split('=', 1) for _ in xrange(len(split)))
            return {k.strip(): v.strip() for k, v in processed_data}
```

This is the initial section of the main script that prompts the above function, and then sets GPS Time as the Dictionary key…

```
while (mypkt.Next()):  #mypkt.Next is an API function in the log processor app I am using – essentially it grabs the whole GPS Info packet shown above
    data = process_data(mypkt.Text, 1)
    packets[data['GPS Time']] = data
```

The code above has no problem splitting the first instance ‘GPS Time’, but it ignores Lonitude, Latitude etc, To make matters worse, there is sometimes a blank line between each packet item too.  I guess I need to store previous dictionary related splits before the ‘return’, but I am having difficulty trying to find out how to do this.

The dict output I am currently getting is…

```
'14:19:09.000': {'GPS Time': '14:19:09.000'},
```

But What I am hoping for is…

```
'14:19:09': {'GPS Time': '14:19:09',
                ‘Longitude’:’000.65341’,
                ‘Latitude’:’+41.25385’,
                ‘Altitude’:’+111.400’},
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

MikG

Comment: Is there one record per file, i.e. one GPS info record consisting of the 4 items GPS TIme, long, lat and alt, or can there be many per file? And are there really blank lines between each item?

Comment: Hi mhawke, there is more than one instance of the GPS packet, however I have tried Daniel's example below and managed to get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All this use of `range(len(whatever))` is nonsense. You almost never need to do that in Python. Just iterate through the thing.

Your problem however is more fundamental: you return from inside the while loop. That means you only ever get one element, because as soon as that first line is processed, you return and the function ends.

Also, you have a `while` loop which means that processing will end as soon as the program encounters a line without an equals; but you have blank lines between each data line, so again execution would never proceed past the first one.

So all you need is:

```
split_data = file_object.split('\n')
result = {}
for line in split_data:
    if '=' in line:
        key, value = line.split('=', 1)
        result[key.strip()] = value.strip()
return result
```

Comment: Hi Daniel Roseman, thank you so much! I have tried it out and it's exactly what I was trying to accomplish. Very much appreciated.